# Is there a way to capture and replay network traffic on demand?

Tags: networking, 13.04

For places with annoying captive portals that you have to log into every day, is there a way to capture and replay traffic (for the login page) when connected to a specific wifi network?

Edit: I have figured out how to bypass the captive portal that annoys me every day with a greasemonkey script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        wifi-autologin
// @namespace   lakdsjf-ns
// @description Hopefully autologins to a wifi network
// @include     https://1.1.1.1/*
// @include     http://1.1.1.1/*
// @version     1
// @run-at document-end
// ==/UserScript==

console.log('loaded');
window.addEventListener('load', submitAction);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about a web-based login screen, there's a good chance it sets a cookie and a corresponding token, which change upon each viewing, in order to protect against [Login CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Forging_login_requests).  This would also prevent what you are trying to do from working.

Basically, this means that the form sets a unique cookie along with a token in a hidden form element, ensuring that the person submitting the form is the same person that requested the page.

On the off-chance that they *don't* do this, you could write a script to login via [curl](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/curl.1.html), and then place that script into `/etc/network/if-up.d/` (as described [here](/etc/network/if-up.d/)).